# Is the Adjoint of the identity element that same identity element?

Tags: linear-algebra

I had a quick question, I was wondering if the adjoint of the identity element of a euclidean space is that same identity element. And if not, why?

(adjoint being the conjugate of the transposed)

Comment: Adjoint in which context? As a map from an inner product space to itself?

Comment: Identity element of what?

Comment: What are you talking about? The adjoint operator of the identity map is always itself...by definition.